# Skrollr animate an element inside, relative to a scrolling div

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am having an issue trying to get an element to animate inside a moving div;

Imagine I have a `div` (blue 800 wide x 100 high) that is off screen, below the screen and when you scroll down it comes into the screen and continues up and disappears out of the top of the screen. I call this `div` "container".

Now imagine if I have a smaller `div` inside the "container" `div`, called "box" and I apply an animation to the "box" moving it from left to right.

I expect that when I scroll down the box will move from left to right inside the container, as the container moves up the screen. (Resulting in the box looking like it is moving diagonally up the screen)

The result I get is that the container moves up the screen, as expected, but the box is now outside of it's container and moves from right to left across the bottom of the screen

I cannot figure out how to make the box move inside it's parent container and scroll up with it.

I think I need to use `relative` mode (or view-port mode) but I can't get it to work at all.

spacer div:

```
<div id="justaspacer" style="height:1000px;"></div>
```

(container div):

```
<div id="container" style="width:800px; background:#D1E3ED; height:100px; margin:auto;></div>
```

(box div):

```
<div id="box" style="background:#00F; width:100px; height:100px;" data-anchor-target="#container" data-100-bottom="left:100%; opacity:0;" data--100-bottom="left:50%;opacity:1;"  data-top="top:80%;">"</div>"
```

This results in the container scrolling up and and the box to fly in from off screen
completely removed from the container.

That is all the code, no other css and only

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/skrollr.min.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/skrollr.ie.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
var s = skrollr.init({
    edgeStrategy: 'set',
    easing: {
        WTF: Math.random,
        inverted: function(p) {
            return 1-p;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

This javascript

Any help would be much appreciated

Been driving me crazy

Hope someone can help

Comment: try position:relative on the container. Edit - also, you are missing the closing quotation mark on the style attribute for that div.

Comment: You should seriously consider using a separate style sheet, it makes everything way easier. Also, don't post two questions on the same topic, especially an hour after the last! You should probably combine the two questions into one or just remove the first because they really are the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Dan said in the comment, you need to position the container relative and the box absolute. You should really learn CSS before trying skrollr.

http://jsbin.com/aWOB/1/edit

```
<div id="container" style="width:800px; background:#D1E3ED; height:100px; margin:auto;position:relative;"></div>
```

---

```
<div id="box" style="background:#00F; width:100px; height:100px;position:absolute;" data-anchor-target="#container" data-bottom="left:100%;margin-left:-100px;" data-top="left:0%;margin-left:0px;"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome answer, was that easy! I do know css, quite well actually but I was at a loss to get skrollr working the way I wanted. The sky is the limit now. Thanks a bunch. I must have missed something in the documentation, the example you posted, or something similar really should be added to the download package. Cheers again.